# Get monthly posts by year in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, archive, posts

I'm looking to get a list of months in 2014 for posts. Such as:

2014
- January
- February
....

I also need the functionality of the class 'active' in there for when I'm on that month.

I've tried a million plugins and messing around with the archives functionality with no luck.

Comment: is widget archives not the one you're looking for? you have it on appearance > widgets

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_custom_post_type_archive_where($where,$args){  
    $post_type  = isset($args['post_type'])  ? $args['post_type']  : 'post';  
    $where = "WHERE post_type = '$post_type' AND post_status = 'publish'";
    return $where;  
}
```

then call this:

```
add_filter( 'getarchives_where','my_custom_post_type_archive_where',10,2);
```

Whenever you want to display archive by custom post type, just pass the post_type args:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'your_post_type',
    'type'         => 'monthly',
    'echo'         => 0
);
echo '<ul>'.wp_get_archives($args).'</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks for this, so where would I put this in regards to what goes in functions.php and what would go in the category.php sidebar? It's for normal posts, not custom post types :)

Comment: If you are using for post, then you have to call:
$args = array(
    'type'         => 'monthly',
    'echo'         => 0
);
echo '<ul>'.wp_get_archives($args).'</ul>'; in category.php or wherever you want to display

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Taxonomies to achieve this, I would have preferred to have it automatically show this but it seemed like the best compromise for now. I will however be giving San Jay's option a go.